# IMS DB command from Master Console does not work

Tags: mainframe, zos, ims-db

Good morning,

Commands from the master console are apparently not processed by IMS11. "/DIS A" for example returns nothing to the operator master console. The name of the IMS system is IVP1. I also tried IVP1DIS A and no results.

In IMS1110.PROCLIB(DFSPBIV1) the parms are:

CMDMCS=Y,

CRC=/,

IMSID=IVP1,

There are 4 IMS jobs running

JOBNAMEs : IMS11RL1, IMS11CR1, IMS11DL1 and IMS11RC1

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

[image]

The results from the SDSF command execution:
[image]

Comment: Is there any respose on the console? If the CRC is not recognized, MVS would resond with message `IEE305I /DIS     COMMAND INVALID`, or `IEE305I IVP1DIS  COMMAND INVALID` in case the `IMSID` is not correct, respectively.

Comment: Hi, I added a picture on the question. You can see the D A,L command that works fine and the /DIS A that returns nothing. Not even an error message. This is from hercules console. From the operator console the behavior is exactly the same. Thank you

Comment: That is the system console (SYSCONS), and IMS command manual only talks about (E)MCS consoles. I don't know if IMS makes a difference about it. I don't have any IMS experience, unfotrunately. Have you tried to issuing the command through TSO SDSF?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to issue the command from TSO SDSF. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Start your TSO session, then SDSF. In SDSF type `/` in the command line, then type your IMS command in the dialog popup and hit enter. Use `ULOG` to see any response from the command.

Comment: I added the Ulog form the commands. No response on Ulog. Thank you.

Comment: IMS is different than Db2 so the -sys command doesn't work.  Drawing from the other answer below, in SDSF you would type `/r 30,/dis` to interact with IMS.  Where /dis is the IMS command you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
After the IMS starts up. There will be a message like "*30 DFS810A IMS READY          22311/2128438 IMS11CR1.IMS11CR1   IVP1".

If you want to send commands to IMS, just Reply to it. For example: R 30,/DIS A
[image]

Thank you very much for you support.

Comment: Note, the message number in your example `30` should be `nn` as it will change with every response.

Answer (score 0):

try "/IVP1DIS A" in SDSF log..   the '/' here is not for CRC.. but for any MVS command issued in spool... Only "IVP1DIS A" should work on the MSTCONS

---

SDSF ULOG  CONSOLE SUBHASH                         LINE 0

COMMAND INPUT ===> **/IVP1DIS A**

********************************* TOP OF DATA ***************

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).